# Compare 2 Objects in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

In my application, I want to compare 2 core data instances of the entity "Workout". I want to check if the 2 objects have identical attribute values for all of their attributes. Essentially if the two objects are the same minus the relationship, whosWorkout. Is there any way to do this without manually checking every single attribute? I know I could do:

```
if(object1.intAttr == object2.intAttr){
    NSLog(@"This attribute is the same");
}
else{
    return;
}

repeat with different attributes...
```

Is there any core data method to make this a bit less tedious?

Answer (score 3):

First I would create an `isEqual` method in the `Workout` subclass like this...

```
-(BOOL)isEqualToWorkout:(Workout*)otherWorkout
{
    return [self.attribute1 isEqual:otherWorkout.attribute1]
        && [self.attribute2 isEqual:otherWorkout.attribute2]
        && [self.attribute3 isEqual:otherWorkout.attribute3]
        && [self.attribute4 isEqual:otherWorkout.attribute4]
        ...;
}
```

Then whenever you want to compare to `Workout` objects just use...

```
BOOL equal = [workout1 isEqualToWorkout:workout2];
```

Comment: It is specifically mentioned in the Core Data documentation you must not override `isEqual:`. Instead, `isEqualToWorkout:` should be created.

Comment: @LeoNathan Edited. Please remove the down vote. I'm typing on my iPhone here so don't have easy access to docs or Xcode :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the attributes by name.

```
for (NSString *attribute in object.entity.attributesByName) {
    if ([[object  valueForKey:attribute] intValue] != 
        [[object2 valueForKey:attribute] intValue]) {
       return NO;
    }
}
return YES;
```

This assumes all integer attributes. You could do a switch statement to check for the class with the `class` method and deal with different data types as well.

Comment: It is a blueprint for any MSManagedObject class.

Comment: Of course it is relevant. A universal solution is more relevant than a specific one. This could be used as the basis for a `NSManagedObject` category to compare two managed objects. How is this not relevant?

Comment: @Foggy I know that == compares pointer addresses. Above, I show how to compare the scalar values instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare whether one object represents a greater or lesser value than another object, you can’t use the standard C comparison operators > and <. Instead, the basic Foundation types, like NSNumber, NSString and NSDate, provide a compare: method:

```
if ([someDate compare:anotherDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {

    // someDate is earlier than anotherDate

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up doing the following:

```
-(BOOL)areEqual:(Workout *)firstWorkout secondWorkout:(Workout *)secondWorkout{
    NSArray *allAttributeKeys = [[[firstWorkout entity] attributesByName] allKeys];

    if([[firstWorkout entity] isEqual:[secondWorkout entity]]
       && [[firstWorkout committedValuesForKeys:allAttributeKeys] isEqual:[secondWorkout committedValuesForKeys:allAttributeKeys]]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got the right idea, but it sounds like you implemented your `-areEqual:...` method in some class other than `Workout`. A more typical pattern is to implement the equality method in the class of the objects that will be compared, `Workout` in this case. That would let you write `if ([workout1 isEqualToWorkout:workout2]) {...}`, which is the usual pattern in Objective-C.

Comment: @Caleb: Workout is a managed object class. If I had done the method in there, neither of the object instances would exist. It is correct to do it in this class, which is the view controller which utilizes the managed object.

Comment: @JosueEspinosa you are mistaken. The entity you are comparing IS a Workout object. It is just the same as any other type if ibject Exocet that it is created and stored in a Core Data store. You can put methods into the Workout subclass that operate on the entities. ... Like in my answer. Try it, it works.